# Apex data loader installation

Tags: data-loader, windows7

After install Apex data loader 29.0 in my notebook(windows 7), I can not find Data Loader icon on desktop, or Start -> All Programs -> salesforce.com. Could someone help on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: This would appear to be an OS related question (Windows 7, locating installed applications) and not relating specifically to Data Loader.

Comment: Did you try just typing **Data Loader** in start menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem. After installing I wondered where the shortcut went.

But later I realised that it is in admin desktop and I copied to my desktop.

It could be present in Admin desktop..

Answer (score 0):

If all the access stuffs are ok with your User Account on your notebook, then first have look at **Control Panel -> Uninstall Program**. Search for **salesforce.com Data Loader**. 
If it's there, you should be able to find the app by just typing **Data Loader** in the Start Menu.

[image: Search Results for Data Loader]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Solved it by changeing the paths and copying the config files to the user profile.
see: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008oc1IAA